# why my strictly unequal function does not work

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to create a function to check if three variables are strictly equal it returns false and true if they are strictly unequal, but both conditions return true, why?

```
var unequal = function(val1, val2, val3) {
  if (val1 !== val2 && val1 !== val3) {
    return true;
  } else if (val1 === val2 || val1 === val3) {
    return false;
  }
};
```

Comment: Don't you also need `&&` for the second test? Also, what if they are neither strictly equal not strictly unequal? What's the function supposed to return?

Comment: _"but both conditions return true"_  -  With what parameters?

Comment: Is this the correct requirement: return true if all are unequal, else return false? If so, you can use `return val1 !== val2 && val1 !== val3`

Comment: can you include some test cases and the expected results? It is not clear for me what do you consider as strictly unequal between three elements, e.g. is it considered in your case strictly unequal if we have an input like `unequal(7,7,20)` ?

Comment: my function should return "true" if  the three variables are not equal and return "false" if any two variables equal example: unequal(1,2,3) gives true, unequal(1,2,2) gives false, unequal(2,2,1) gives false and so on

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple one-liner

```
var unequal = function(val1, val2, val3) {
  return val1 !== val2 || val1 !== val3 || val2 !== val3;
};
```